# I am trying to use pagination in my online exam based project but the script here is not working

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to make an online exam project for which I need to send these 4 values to another page using ajax, but the script seems to be not working.

```
// fetching records
function displayRecords(numRecords, pageNum) {
  alert(numRecords);
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "button.php",
    data: "show=" + numRecords + "&pagenum=" + pageNum,
    val12:x,
    catg12:catg,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
               $("#tabs1-html").html(data);      
              }
  });                      
 }

 // used when user change row limit
 function changeDisplayRowCount(numRecords) {
   displayRecords(numRecords, 1);
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.tab12').click(function(){
   var catg = $('#cat').val();
   var x = $(this).val();
 });

 displayRecords(5, 1);
```

Can someone advise me on where I'm wrong

Comment: What about it is not working? You only show your javascript, but not your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

When sending number of params via ajax, you should put them inside the curly brackets like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "button.php",
    data: {
      show: numRecords,
      pagenum: pageNum,
      val12: x,
      catg12: catg,
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
               $("#tabs1-html").html(data);      
             }
  });
```

Second problem is that `x` and `catg` are undefined within `displayRecords()`, you must pass them as parameters, just like you did with `numRecords` and `pageNum`, so define the function as `displayRecords(numRecords, pageNum, x, catg)`

And then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.tab12').click(function(){
   var catg = $('#cat').val();
   var x = $(this).val();
   displayRecords(5, 1, x, catg); 
});
```

Hope it helps